# What's the best way to optimize a query of search 1000 rows in 50 million by date? Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE ard_signals
(id, val, str, date_val, dt);
```

This table records the values ​​of all ID's signals. Unique ID's around 950. At the moment, the table contains about 50 million rows with different values of these signals. Each ID can have only a numeric values, string values or date values.

I get the last value of each ID, which, by condition, is less than input date:

```
select ID,
       max(val) keep (dense_rank last order by dt desc) as val,
       max(str) keep (dense_rank last order by dt desc) as str,
       max(date_val) keep (dense_rank lastt order by dt desc) as date_val,
       max(dt)
 where dt <= to_date(any_date)
 group by id;
```

I have index on ID. At the moment, the request takes about 30 seconds. Help, please, what ways of optimization it is possible to make for the given request?

EXPLAIN PLAN: [with dt index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M6N2.jpg)

Example Data(This kind of rows are about 950-1000):

| ID | VAL | STR | DATE_VAL | DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 920 | 0 |  |  | 20.07.2022 9:59:11 |
| 490 |  | yes |  | 20.07.2022 9:40:01 |
| 565 | 233 |  |  | 20.07.2022 9:32:03 |
| 32 | 1 |  |  | 20.07.2022 9:50:01 |

Comment: index on dt too

Comment: You can index by timestamp. Now, if the samples are going to grow significantly over time, maybe a time series database like InfluxDB, TimescaleDB, etc. could be faster.

Comment: @TheImpaler I tried but the query still uses TABLE ACCESS FULL and takes 30 seconds

Comment: Do you really need `dense_rank last`? That means you want to find all rows in the same *last* `dt` and pick the max value from it. Now, if you just needed the value from the last row, it would be much faster.

Comment: Your title says you are searching 1000 rows; does that mean the date filter will restrict the analytic functions to only look at 1000 rows (which would probably utilise an index on `dt`); or since you also mention 950 IDs, that the *result* is ~1000 but you're actually looking at all, or most of, the data? In other words how selective is the `dt <= x` condition - what would `select count(*) from your_table where dt <= to_date(any_date)` return? 1000? 1 million? 25 million? Your real query and execution plan would be helpful.

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query where the table has the new index. However, if your WHERE clause is not significantly reducing the volume of data being returned then the optimiser may not use the index e.g. if your table has data for the last 3 years and your where clause is "where dt <= to_date("2022-08-01)" then using the index v. a full table scan is unlikely to produce a performance improvement

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, since I need to find out all the values ​​of each unique ID

Comment: Your query returns max(dt), and for the other columns you specify 'last order by dt desc', so, if I'm not mistaken you get the values for the earliest day. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @AlexPoole this query returning 30 million rows. The problem is that the last value of some ID can be deep at the bottom of the table.

Comment: @RickPat You say for each unique `id`, but the query is grouping by `dt`. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not 100% clear to me. It sounds easy and the solution should be very performant... if we understand what you need.

Comment: @NickW I attached a screenshot of the plan to the post.

Comment: @TheImpaler - I think from "can have only a numeric values, string values or date values" the row with the last date will only have *one* of those three not-null; so for an ID the most recent value in each of the three columns will come from different rows. It's not entirely clear though...

Comment: @TheImpaler I created an example of out data

Comment: @AlexPoole yes exactly. Sorry if I didn't make it clear to you earlier.

Comment: @RickPat That's perfectly OK. Now, what would be the expected result for your sample data? Feel free to adapt it if you think it can show the case in a better way.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have attached a table with an example data set. Such entries from ID #1 to ID#950

Comment: You may create an index on `id` and `dt` columns, find maximum date per `id` using index and then perform self-join using index access also. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=692f7e4d2160604cae407482fcd0f964)

Comment: @RickPat - saw your now deleted comment regarding my answer.  You're right - I was being lazy with the `ROWNUM` trick.  I updated the answer to use hints to prevent unnesting of the scalar subquery.  Hopefully you find it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need your application to maintain a table of distinct `id` values.

So, you want the last record for each group (distinct `id` value) in your table, *without* doing a full table scan.  It *seems* like it should be easy to tell Oracle: iterate through the distinct values for `id` and then do an index lookup to get the last `dt` value for each `id` and then give me that row.  But looks are deceiving here -- it's not easy at all, if it is even possible.

Think about what an index on `(id)` (or `(id, dt)`) has.  It has a bunch of leaf blocks and a structure to find the **highest** value of `id` in each block.  But Oracle can only use the index to get all the distinct `id` values by reading every leaf block in the index.  So, we might be find a way to trade our `TABLE FULL SCAN` for an `INDEX_FFS` for a marginal benefit, but it's not really what we're hoping for.

What about partitioning?  Can't we create `ARD_SIGNALS` with `PARTITION BY LIST (id) AUTOMATIC` and use that?  Now the data dictionary is guaranteed to have a separate partition for each distinct `id` value.

But again - think about what Oracle knows (from `DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS`) -- it knows what the **highest** partition key value is in each partition.  It is true: for a list partitioned table, that highest value is guaranteed to be the only distinct value in the partition.  But I think using that guarantee requires special optimizations that Oracle's CBO does not seem to make (yet).

So, unfortunately, you are going to need to modify your application to keep a parent table for `ARDS_SIGNALS` that has a (single) row for each distinct `id`.

Even then, it's kind of difficult to get what we want.  Because, again, want Oracle to iterate through the distinct `id` values, then use the index to find the one with the highest `dt` for that `id` .. **and then stop**.  So, we're looking for an execution plan that makes use of the `INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)` operation.

I find that tricky with joins, but not so hard with scalar subqueries.  So, assuming we named our parent table `ARD_IDS`, we can start with this:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_UNNEST(@ssq) */ i.id, 
       ( SELECT /*+ QB_NAME(ssq) */ max(dt) 
         FROM ard_signals s 
         WHERE s.id = i.id 
         AND s.dt <= to_date(trunc(SYSDATE) + 2+ 10/86400) -- replace with your date variable
        ) max_dt
FROM   ard_ids i;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name           | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      22 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.02 |    3021 |
|   2 |   FIRST ROW                  |                |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |    3021 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)| ARD_SIGNALS_N1 |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |    3021 |
|   4 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL           | ARD_IDS        |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      22 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("S"."ID"=:B1 AND "S"."DT"<=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)+2+.00011574074074074074
              0740740740740740740741)))
```

Note the use of hints to keep Oracle from merging the scalar subquery into the rest of the query and losing our desired access path.

Next, it is a matter of using those `(id, max(dt))` combinations to look up the rows from the table to get the other column values.  I came up with this; improvements may be possible (especially if `(id, dt)` is not as selective as I am assuming it is):

```
with k AS (
select /*+ NO_UNNEST(@ssq) */ i.id, ( SELECT /*+ QB_NAME(ssq) */ max(dt) FROM ard_signals s WHERE s.id = i.id AND s.dt <= to_date(trunc(SYSDATE) + 2+ 10/86400) ) max_dt
from   ard_ids i
) 
SELECT k.id,
       max(val) keep ( dense_rank first order by dt desc, s.rowid ) val,
       max(str) keep ( dense_rank first order by dt desc, s.rowid ) str,
       max(date_val) keep ( dense_rank first order by dt desc, s.rowid ) date_val,
       max(dt) keep ( dense_rank first order by dt desc, s.rowid ) dt
FROM   k 
INNER JOIN ard_signals s ON s.id = k.id AND s.dt = k.max_dt
GROUP BY k.id;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name           | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.04 |    7009 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY                       |                |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.04 |    7009 |   302K|   302K|  268K (0)|
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                       |                |      1 |   1005 |   1000 |00:00:00.04 |    7009 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                      |                |      1 |   1005 |   1000 |00:00:00.03 |    6009 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                | ARD_IDS        |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | ARD_SIGNALS_N1 |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.02 |    6006 |       |       |          |
|   6 |      SORT AGGREGATE                  |                |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.02 |    3002 |       |       |          |
|   7 |       FIRST ROW                      |                |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |    3002 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)    | ARD_SIGNALS_N1 |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |    3002 |       |       |          |
|   9 |    TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| ARD_SIGNALS    |   1000 |      1 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |    1000 |       |       |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("S"."ID"="I"."ID" AND "S"."DT"=)
   8 - access("S"."ID"=:B1 AND "S"."DT"<=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!)+2+.000115740740740740740740740740740740740741)))
```

... 7000 gets and 4/100ths of a second.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can put a selective lower bound on how old the last `dt` value will be for each `id`, you can probably just add `AND dt >= :lower_bound` for a pretty big improvement without doing all the other stuff I said in my answer.  Depending on how good your lower bound value is.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `rownum <= 1` takes the earliest result in the table. The final query will not display the nearest date. Works fast, but not what needed :(

Comment: I tried your updated solution. Unfortunately, it takes 3 min 30 sec, which is 7 times longer than my original request...

Comment: @RickPat - I ran it on my 19c instance against 55 million rows and got the results posted.  Is `(id, dt)` selective on your table?

Comment: I noticed that my index was set incorrectly. Now the request is executed correctly and quickly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to see that latest entry per ID at a given time.

If you would usually be interested in times at the beginning of the recordings, an index on the time could help to limit the rows to have to work with. But I consider this highly unlikely.

It is much more likely that you are interested in the situation at more recent times. This means for instance that when looking for the latest entries until today, for one ID the latest entry may be found yesterday, while for another ID the latest entry my be from two years ago.

In my opinion, Oracle already chooses the best approach to deal with this: read the whole table sequentially.

If you have several CPUs at hand, parallel execution might speed up things:

```
select /*+ parallel(4) */ ...
```

If you really need this to be much faster, then you may want to consider an additional table with one row per ID, which gets a copy of the lastest date and value by a trigger. I.e. you'd introduce redundancy for the gain of speed, as it is done in data warehouses.